# How to set dimension alias on Google Analytics Core reporting API V4 using PHP

Tags: php, pagination, google-analytics-api

I'm working on integrating Google Analytics Reporting API v4 to my website using [Google Analytics Core Reporting API V4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/#features)

I have setup reporting api to return max 10 results. My problem is that I can't find how do I get next or previous 10 results as it is always returning first 10.

Is there a way to get next and / or previous 10 results with Google Analytics  Core Reporting API v4?

my PHP code below:

```
// Create the ReportRequest object.   

$request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();  
$request->setViewId($VIEW_ID);   
$request->setDateRanges($dateRange); 
$request->setPageSize(10);  
//===========================================================      
//  HOW DO I SET TO SHOW DIFFERENT PAGE THAN A FIRST PAGE     
//  HOW DO I SHOW RESULTS 20-30   
//===========================================================

//$request->setPageToken($page_token); 

$request->setDimensions($dimensions);   
$request->setMetrics($metrics);  
$request->setDimensionFilterClauses($dimensionFilterClause);
$request->setMetricFilterClauses(array($metricFilterClause));
$request->setOrderBys($ordering); 
$body = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();  
$body->setReportRequests( array( $request) );   
return  $analytics->reports->batchGet( $body );
```

I have found that there is a function setPageToken() and function getPageToken() which I assume has to do something with that.

Can someone explain how to do that? the example would be very useful. Thank you.

Comment: I'll provide a full answer in the if I have time later on, but first solution: setPageSize > 10. It is better to make more efficient use of an API than make multiple request (quotas are in place) secondly when your response comes back there should be a value in the `getNextPageToken()` use that token to make your next request by calling [`setPageToken()`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#ReportRequest.FIELDS.page_token) on your next request.

Comment: Hi Matt in which class do i find getNextPageToken() method? I have tried with ReportRequest class but this class gives me an error as there is no method called getNextPageToken: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest::getNextPageToken(). Can you give an example and a little guidence?

Comment: The PHP client libraries are generated from the resource description which can be found in the [Reference docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet). Thus `getNextPageToken` method would be on the [`Report`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#report) class in the response.

Answer (score 3):

#### Client Libraries

The [PHP client libraries](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/) are generated from the resource descriptions found in the [reference docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#report). Any `Object()` will become a class in the PHP client library. For example the [`Object(Metric]`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#metric) will become [`Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric`](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client-services/blob/master/src/Google/Service/AnalyticsReporting/Metric.php). It is important to be able to look at the Resource description and understand the structure of the generated classes, short of that use the generated source to guide you thorugh how the classes are strucutred.

Thus in your question title you ask: **"How to set dimension alias?"** If you look at the resource description and the generated source you will notice only the `Metric` class has the property `alias`. This is because the `Metric` object takes an `expression` field, not a `name` field. You can in fact provide a mathematical expression such as `ga:sessions * ga:users` but such a string can be confusing thus you might want to set an `alias` for that `expression`.

#### API limits and quotas

You are requesting 10 rows at a time and wanting to paginate through them. I would strongly encourage you to make the maximum request to make the most efficient use of your [API quota](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/limits-quotas#reporting_apis). The API is a shared resource and if you make inefficient use of it, it won't take you as far. With that said I will describe how to do pagination below.

#### Pagination PHP

Let's assume you know how to make a successful request with auth and everything since you carefully read the [Hello Analytics PHP](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-php) guide:

```
  // Create the ReportRequest object.
  $request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
  $request->setViewId($VIEW_ID);
  $request->setDateRanges($dateRange);
  $request->setMetrics($metrics);
  $request->setDimensions($dimensions);

  $body = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
  $body->setReportRequests( array( $request) );
  $response = $analytics->reports->batchGet( $body );
```

Awesome, well done. The hard part is behind you. You are a clever coder so you are going to hold onto that `$response` and `$request` because you suspect they might be important. So you go ahead and parse the response:

```
  for ( $reportIndex = 0; $reportIndex < count( $response ); $reportIndex++ ) {
    $report = $response[ $reportIndex ];
    $header = $report->getColumnHeader();
    $dimensionHeaders = $header->getDimensions();
    $metricHeaders = $header->getMetricHeader()->getMetricHeaderEntries();
    $rows = $report->getData()->getRows();
    $nextPageToken = $report->getNextPageToken();
    ...
    }
```

You got some nice information out of that report, some Dimensions and Metrics looks like your new ecommerce site is doing well. So well in fact that you need to get more data from this report since you hit the [pageSize](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#ReportRequest.FIELDS.page_size) before you got all the rows you needed to plan your Q3 strategy. That's okay, you are a clever coder and you held onto that `$request` and that `$nextPageToken`. You know exactly what to do; you are going to call the API again with the `$nextPageToken`:

```
  $request->setPageToken($nextPageToken);

  $body = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
  $body->setReportRequests( array( $request) );
  $response = $analytics->reports->batchGet( $body );
```

Thus you have just paginated through multiple pages. Rinse wash and repeat.
For those who would like the `JSON` equivalent here you go:

### JSON Pagination example

Original Request:

```
{
  "reportRequests": 
  [
    {
      "viewId": "XXXX",
      "metrics": 
      [
        {
          "expression": "ga:users"
        }
      ],
      "dimensions": 
      [
        {
          "name": "ga:pagepath"
        },
        {
          "name": "ga:browser"
        },
        {
          "name": "ga:country"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Response:

```
{
 "reports": [
  {
   "columnHeader": {
    "dimensions": [
     "ga:pagepath",
     "ga:browser",
     "ga:country"
    ],
    "metricHeader": {
     "metricHeaderEntries": [
      {
       "name": "ga:users",
       "type": "INTEGER"
      }
     ]
    }
   },
   "data": {
    "rows": [
    ...

    ],
    "totals": [
     {
      "values": [
       "3739"
      ]
     }
    ],
    "rowCount": 1109,
    "minimums": [
     {
      "values": [
       "1"
      ]
     }
    ],
    "maximums": [
     {
      "values": [
       "359"
      ]
     }
    ]
   },
   "nextPageToken": "1000"
  }
 ]
}
```

Second Request:

```
{
  "reportRequests": 
  [
    {
      "viewId": "XXXX",
      "metrics": 
      [
        {
          "expression": "ga:users"
        }
      ],
      "dimensions": 
      [
        {
          "name": "ga:pagepath"
        },
        {
          "name": "ga:browser"
        },
        {
          "name": "ga:country"
        }
      ],
      "pageToken": "1000"
    }
  ]
}
```